# Why is there no voice audio during Watch_Dogs cutscenes?

Tags: watch-dogs

I can't expand much more on the question, it says mostly everything. I have all my audio settings maxed. There is audio during the phone calls while roaming, however as soon as a cut scene starts, *only* voice audio is gone, everything else, like sound effects and music, is fine.

I was wondering how this might be fixed, and what may be causing it.

Comment: This is a known issue and there should be a patch for it soon. In the meantime try disabling surround sound.

Comment: I will try that when I get on my desktop in a while, thank you.

Comment: Disabling surround didn't work, any other ideas? Also is the patch out for this?

Answer (score -2):

Watch Dogs sound can be fixed very easily.  Follow the steps

**1.** Before installing watch dogs you have to change the sound bit rate in control panel-sound-speakers-play back devices. Change the audio bit rate to 24bit 48000Hz. step

**2.** Then install the game and after installation shutdown your computer for 5mins and then restart it. 
Start the game and you will hear the sound. If you don't hear sound then put a new sound card in your computer or update the sound driver.

*Another thing is that the graphic card you are using doesn't support the game well, so you want to purchase a better or higher series of the nvidia 2gb graphic card for more acceleration of the game.*